# Ошибка при загрузке базы данных MySQL на сервер (Error 1064)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Версия сервера 5.7.20

Помогите найти ошибку

```sql
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ws
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ws
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ws` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `ws` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Izdelie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Izdelie` (
  `Articul` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Width` INT NOT NULL,
  `Lenght` INT NOT NULL,
  `Image` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cmments` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Articul`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`User`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`User` (
  `Login` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Passw` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Count` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Login`, `Passw`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Order` (
  `Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Stage` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Client` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Manager` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  `Price` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Number`, `Date`),
  INDEX `fk_Order_User1_idx` (`Client` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Order_User2_idx` (`Manager` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Client`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`User` (`Login`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_User2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Manager`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`User` (`Login`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Custom_Izdelie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Custom_Izdelie` (
  `OrderNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `ArticulIdelie` INT NOT NULL,
  `Count` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderNumber`, `ArticulIdelie`),
  INDEX `fk_Custom_Izdelie_Izdelie1_idx` (`ArticulIdelie` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Custom_Izdelie_Order`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrderNumber`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Order` (`Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Custom_Izdelie_Izdelie1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ArticulIdelie`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Izdelie` (`Articul`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '         ';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Tkan_Izdelie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Tkan_Izdelie` (
  `ArticulTkan` INT NOT NULL,
  `ArticulIzdelie` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ArticulTkan`, `ArticulIzdelie`),
  INDEX `fk_Tkan_Izdelie_Izdelie1_idx` (`ArticulIzdelie` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tkan_Izdelie_Izdelie1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ArticulIzdelie`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Izdelie` (`Articul`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Tkan`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Tkan` (
  `Articul` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Color` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  `Pic` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sostav` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  `Width` INT NOT NULL,
  `Lenght` INT NOT NULL,
  `Price` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Articul`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tkan_Tkan_Izdelie1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Articul`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Tkan_Izdelie` (`ArticulTkan`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Storage_Tkan`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Storage_Tkan` (
  `Rulon` INT NOT NULL,
  `ArticulTkan` INT NOT NULL,
  `Width` INT NOT NULL,
  `Length` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Rulon`, `ArticulTkan`),
  INDEX `fk_Storage_Tkan_Tkan1_idx` (`ArticulTkan` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Storage_Tkan_Tkan1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ArticulTkan`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Tkan` (`Articul`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Furnitura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Furnitura` (
  `Articul` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Width` INT NOT NULL,
  `Length` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weight` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Articul`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Furnitura_Izdelie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Furnitura_Izdelie` (
  `Articul_Furnitura` INT NOT NULL,
  `Articul_Izdelie` INT NOT NULL,
  `Pos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Width` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lenght` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rotate` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Count` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Articul_Izdelie`, `Articul_Furnitura`),
  INDEX `fk_Furnitura_Izdelie_Furnitura1_idx` (`Articul_Furnitura` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Furnitura_Izdelie_Izdelie1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Articul_Izdelie`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Izdelie` (`Articul`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Furnitura_Izdelie_Furnitura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Articul_Furnitura`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Furnitura` (`Articul`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ws`.`Storage_Furnitura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Storage_Furnitura` (
  `Party` INT NOT NULL,
  `Articul_Furnitura` INT NOT NULL,
  `Count` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Party`, `Articul_Furnitura`),
  INDEX `fk_Storage_Furnitura_Furnitura1_idx` (`Articul_Furnitura` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Storage_Furnitura_Furnitura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Articul_Furnitura`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Furnitura` (`Articul`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Executing SQL script in server
>   ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
>     INDEX `fk_Order_User2_idx` (`Manager` ASC) VISIBLE,
>     CONSTRAINT `fk_' at line 12
>   SQL Code:
>           -- -----------------------------------------------------
>           -- Table `ws`.`Order`
>           -- -----------------------------------------------------
>           CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Order` (
>             `Number` INT NOT NULL,
>             `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
>             `Stage` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>             `Client` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>             `Manager` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
>             `Price` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>             PRIMARY KEY (`Number`, `Date`),
>             INDEX `fk_Order_User1_idx` (`Client` ASC) VISIBLE,
>             INDEX `fk_Order_User2_idx` (`Manager` ASC) VISIBLE,
>             CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_User1`
>               FOREIGN KEY (`Client`)
>               REFERENCES `ws`.`User` (`Login`)
>               ON DELETE NO ACTION
>               ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
>             CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_User2`
>               FOREIGN KEY (`Manager`)
>               REFERENCES `ws`.`User` (`Login`)
>               ON DELETE NO ACTION
>               ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>           ENGINE = InnoDB
>
>  SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>
>  Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>  Nothing to fetch
>  Executing SQL script in server
>  ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
>    INDEX `fk_Order_User2_idx` (`Manager` ASC) VISIBLE,
>    CONSTRAINT `fk_' at line 12
>  SQL Code:
>           -- -----------------------------------------------------
>           -- Table `ws`.`Order`
>           -- -----------------------------------------------------
>           CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Order` (
>             `Number` INT NOT NULL,
>             `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
>             `Stage` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>             `Client` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>             `Manager` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
>             `Price` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>             PRIMARY KEY (`Number`, `Date`),
>             INDEX `fk_Order_User1_idx` (`Client` ASC) VISIBLE,
>             INDEX `fk_Order_User2_idx` (`Manager` ASC) VISIBLE,
>             CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_User1`
>               FOREIGN KEY (`Client`)
>               REFERENCES `ws`.`User` (`Login`)
>               ON DELETE NO ACTION
>               ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
>             CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_User2`
>               FOREIGN KEY (`Manager`)
>               REFERENCES `ws`.`User` (`Login`)
>               ON DELETE NO ACTION
>               ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>           ENGINE = InnoDB
>
>  SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>
>  Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>  Nothing to fetch
> ```

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке явно сказано, что ему не нравится слово visible у индекса. И еще в сообщении упоминается, что возможно не та версия MySQL. И действительно visible есть только в MySQL 8.0. Уберите это слово

Comment: Спасибо удалил visible и всё загрузилось :)